# How to sample efficiently from a list like [[0,1],[0,6],[0,7],[1,4],[1,8]], ideally in pytorch (so this will be a tensor)

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a tensor that looks like

```
[[0,1],
 [0,6],
 [0,7],
 [1,4],
 [1,8],
 [2,5],
 [2,7]]
```

so the first column is always a non-decreasing sequence from 0 to N (N is fixed), and the second column is some integer (within a fixed range). For the sampling, I want to obtain one sample from the second column for each distinct number in the first column. In this example, I want to get one sample from [1,6,7] for 0,  one sample from [4,8] for 1, and one sample from [5,7] for 2, and valid examples of samples can be [1,8,7], [7,8,7], etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from random import choice

tnsr = [[0, 1], [0, 6], [0, 7], [1, 4], [1, 8], [2, 5], [2, 7]]

choices = [choice(list(grp))[1] for key, grp in groupby(tnsr, key=itemgetter(0))]
```